# tengo que hacer un trabajo donde liste en pantalla numeros aleatorios(eso ya lo tengo) y luego esos numeros ordenarlos de menor a mayor alguna

Tags: java

[image: Números Aleatorios]

Ordenar NºAleatorios de menor a mayor

Comment: Primero que nada, el código es texto, no imágenes... trátalo como tal! En cuanto a tu pregunta, solo mostrar números no sirve de nada! Necesitas meterlos en un array, ordenarlo y luego mostrarlo. Hay cientos de ejemplos de algoritmos de ordenación sencillitos tanto en google como aquí en SO, así que te recomiendo que investigues e intentes hacerlo tú mismo. Un saludo y bienvenido a SO.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te ha comentado Benito-B, necesitas introducirlos en un arreglo o lista. Te recomiendo usar un ArrayList.

```
int aleatorio = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y dentro del bucle los vas añadiendo:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

aleatorio = (int)(Math.random()*100);
numeros.add(aleatorio);
}
```

Y para ordenarlos y ver esta lista ordenada (de menor a mayor):

```
Collections.sort(numeros);

 for (int i=0;i<numeros.size();i++) {
      
      System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
    }
```

Para otro tipo de ordenación, tienes que crear una clase que implemente la interface *Comparator*.

Espero que te sirva. Ánimo